# Replacement rule for unevaluated LaplaceTransform

Tags: replacement

I am wanting to algebraically manipulate expressions resulting from LaplaceTransform applied to time domain expressions. Unknown variables are left unevaluated by the transform as they should be. I wish to replace unevaluated transform expressions with the traditional forms.

For example: LaplaceTransform[x[t],t,s] -> x[s]

Here is my naïve attempt which doesn't work:

```
eqs = -((k1 + k2)  LaplaceTransform[x1[t], t, s]) + 
    k2  LaplaceTransform[x2[t], t, s] - 
    m1  (s^2  LaplaceTransform[x1[t], t, s] - s  x1[0] - 
       Derivative[1][x1][0]) == 
   dmp1  (s  LaplaceTransform[x1[t], t, s] - x1[0]);

eqs /. Unevaluated[LaplaceTransform[v_[t], t, s]] -> v[s]

(*-((k1+k2) LaplaceTransform[x1[t],t,s])+k2 \
LaplaceTransform[x2[t],t,s]-m1 (s^2 LaplaceTransform[x1[t],t,s]-s \
x1[0]-(x1^\[Prime])[0])\[Equal]dmp1 (s \
LaplaceTransform[x1[t],t,s]-x1[0])*)
```

Could someone please suggest an approach that works?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following will work for you?

```
Unprotect[LaplaceTransform];

LaplaceTransform/:MakeBoxes[LaplaceTransform[x_Symbol[t_], t_, s_], StandardForm] := RowBox[{toCap[x], "[",MakeBoxes@s,"]"}]

Protect[LaplaceTransform];

toCap[x_Symbol] := With[{s=SymbolName[x]},
    If[LowerCaseQ @ s, ToUpperCase[s], OverscriptBox[s, "^"]]
]
```

Example:

```
LaplaceTransform[f'[t],t,s]
```

> -f[0] + s F[s]

Comment: Thanks, Carl. That is close to working. But it results in symbols enclosed in OverHat which appear to interfere with the use of Solve. Can it be modified to keep symbols in lower case so they don't conflict with reserved symbols, and to eliminate the OverHat?

Comment: I don't see why the OverHat interferes with Solve, since it is just a formatting construct, the underlying expression is still just a LaplaceTransform object. Perhaps you are using `Solve[..., F[s]]` when you should be using `Solve[..., LaplaceTransform[f[t], t, s]]`? I used OverHat/uppercase since I assumed you wouldn't want to use both f[0] and f[s] in your outputs, where the f[0] is in the t domain, and the f[s] is in the s domain.

Comment: Thank you, Carl. That was the problem. I’ve been using Mathematica for a very long time. I consider myself a sophisticated user. But your incantations are a mystery to me.  thanks again!